# remove extra quote from a string at the beginning and in between by regular expression

Tags: nsregularexpression

we want to remove quote (double or single) at the beginning, end or in between by regular expression.

example

1. "LLC "ZORSOFTKZ"'"  -- > expected result "LLC ZORSOFTKZ'"
2. "ADVANCED TRANSFORMATION""  -- > expected result "ADVANCED TRANSFORMATION"
3. ""CENTRUM INFORMATYKI ""ZETO"" SA"" -- > expected result "CENTRUM INFORMATYKI ZETO SA"
4. ""PUBLIC AUTHORITY FOR CONSUMERPROTECTION,(PACP)"" -- > expected result "PUBLIC AUTHORITY FOR CONSUMERPROTECTION,(PACP)"
5. "
   " -- > expected result ""

thanks
Anish

we are looking for the solution using regular expression.